# Convert and cast asking for parameter in microsoft query

Tags: parameters, casting

I don't understand why it is asking me for a parameter in Microsoft Query. This conversion works in other queries and fine in a different program
Our database has the date field as an INT such as '20140507'. I use this to get data that is worthwhile when I bring it back to Excel or as below to compare the system date to the INT value.

Can someone please take a look? SQL server 2008

```
Select 
      sum(SPSYS15.qty) as qty,
      SPSYS15.sku_no,
      SPSYS15.loc_code
    From
      SPSYS15
    Where
      spsys15.source = 'S' and
      SPSYS15.trans_date >= (Convert([Char](8),GetDate() - 30,112))
    Group by 

      SPSYS15.sku_no,
      SPSYS15.loc_code
```

Comment: working on my machine. Can you share the error as well

Comment: It comes up and asks to enter a parameter. The dialog box has 'Char' like it's expecting something.

Comment: Sorry mate, I missed your response last night, can you please share the screenshot or something so that we can get the feel.